# Why isn't LinearModelFit behaving consistently at different levels of lists?

Tags: fitting

I get the following results when I run the following regression on `datass`:

```
datass = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}};
testsOls = LinearModelFit[datass, x, x];

FittedModel[1.2 + 0.5x]

testsOls["FitResiduals"]
{-0.2, -1.7, -0.7, 0.3, 2.3}
```

However, when I run `LinearModelFit` in sublists like the following, I get a different type of result:

```
datas = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}}, 
        {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {9, 9}, {8, 6}, {5, 5}}};
testOls = LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & @@@ datas

{FittedModel[-1. + 1.x], FittedModel[2. + 1.x]}

Through[testOls["FitResiduals"]]
{{2.22045*10^-16, -2.22045*10^-16}, {-8.88178*10^-16, 0.}}
```

I ran `Clear["Global*']` many times and even exited Mathematica before reopening and rerunning both experiments.

Why do I

1. Get different FittedModels for the same data (`datass = datas[[1]]`) and
2. The `Dimensions` of my `FitResiduals` in the second experiment is `[2,2]` as opposed to `[2,5]`?

Comment: use `Map (/@)`, that is,  `testOls = LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & /@ datas`, (not `Apply (@@@)`).

Comment: @kglr Thanks. It works. But why not Apply? I thought the correct application was `f@@@datas = {f[{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}], 
 f[{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {9, 9}, {8, 6}, {5, 5}]}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use [`Map (/@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) in place
   of [`Apply (@@@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
testOls = LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & /@ datas
```

> {FittedModel[1.2 + 0.5 x], FittedModel[2. + 0.666667 x]}

2. If you have to use `Apply (@@@)` you can do

```
LinearModelFit[{##}, x, x] & @@@ datas
```

> {FittedModel[1.2 +0.5 x],FittedModel[2. +0.666667 x]}

#### ... why not *Apply*?

To see why does `LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & @@@ datas` not work try

```
foo[#, x, x] & @@@ datas
```

> {foo[{0, 1}, x, x], foo[{3, 4}, x, x]}

That is, when you use `@@@` you are effectively using

```
{LinearModelFit[{0, 1}, x, x], LinearModelFit[{3, 4}, x, x]}
```

which, correctly, gives

> {FittedModel[-1.+1. x],FittedModel[2. +1. x]}

Comment: What I still find hard to understand is the following: `f @@@ datas` returns the whole list `{f[{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}], f[{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {9, 9}, {8, 6}, {5, 5}]}`. 

I would expect that `foo[#, x, x] & @@@ datas` returned `{foo[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}}, x, x], foo[{{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {9, 9}, {8, 6}, {5, 5}}, x, x]}` the whole list. 

But no. Instead, Map returns `foo` with the whole list. Where is the error in my reasoning?

Comment: @ThadeuFreitasFilho, `foo[##, x, x] & @@@ datas` (note the [`SlotSequence (##)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html)) returns `{foo[{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}, x, x], foo[{{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {9, 9}, {8, 6}, {5, 5}}, x, x]}`, that is it picks all slots from `datas`; and  `foo[#, x, x] & @@@ datas` picks the first slot (`#` which is the same as `#1`)  from `datas` and `foo[#4, x, x] & @@@ datas`  picks the forth slot etc. `foo[{##}, x, x] & @@@ datas` picks all slots wrapped in `List ({ ..}`. Hope this helps.